# How to test if my data fits a uniform distribution with SAS?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, sas, uniform-distribution

1. I have a target variable with upper and lower natural limits (cannot be negative and can not be bigger than 100). Therefore, I would like to know if I could use `Proc UNIVARIATE` (in SAS) to see if the uniform distribution (or Beta distribution with alpha=beta=1) fits my target variable.
2. If the uniform distribution fits my data, would you still recommend to try to explain the variation in this non-normally distributed target variable by building some regression models? I know regression does not assume that the variables are normally distributed (only the errors), but still do not feel confident.
3. I would also like to do some ANOVA models, and in case my variable is not normal I do not know how to proceed. Do you have any idea?

Comment: What is the actual variable? What is the nature of the limits? Eg is this like screening people so that only those between two values are included? Are the limits from the limits of a measurement device? Something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## 1 Testing for uniformity

Let us just try:

**Create data** v0 is uniformly distributed, v10 is manifestly not;

```
data semiUniform;
    array v {0:10} v0-v10;
    do i = 0 to 99;
        linear = uniform(610330341);
        square = linear * linear;
        do j = 0 to 10;
            v{j} = 10 * (j * square + (10-j) * linear);
        end;
        output;
    end;
```

**Test for uniformity**;

```
proc univariate data=semiUniform;
    histogram /beta (alpha=1 beta=1 theta=0 sigma=100);
    var v:;
run;
```

## 2. Regression models

Of course you can. With uniform distributions (especially in the independent variables) I would even expect less issues with influential observations.

Comment: Hi Dirk! Thank you so much for your response. I was on vacations, so sorry about the delay in mine. I used the code you posted, It work wunderfully! THANKS!. Maybe one more question, so my target has a uniform distibution I want to know if how to calculate the CI (considering that this is no longer a normally distributed varaible)

Answer (score 0):

NIST has a [suite](http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/toolkit/rng/documentation_software.html) for testing the randomness of random number generated sequences. They have tests for uniformity, correlations etc.

I would start there, maybe pick the relevant tests and implement them for your case. They have documentation and the software itself for download.